# Receiving POST text/xml request with binary data instead of XML - Python

Tags: python, django, xml, soap, binary

I'm subscribed to a data service that sends out 2 POST requests every minute.

The content type is text/XML:

```
{'Host': 'my.host.com', 'X-Real-Ip': '111.1.181.11', 'X-Forwarded-For': '111.1.181.11', 'X-Forwarded-Proto': 'https', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '8556', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'Accept-Encoding': 'identity,gzip', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Soapaction': '"http://datex2.eu/wsdl/supplierPush/2_0/putDatex2Data"', 'User-Agent': 'Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.0'}
```

I save the request to a file so that I can inspect its contents using the following function:

```py
def receive_post_request_and_save_it_to_file(request):

    if request.method == "GET":
        return redirect("/")

    elif request.method == "POST":
        if request.content_type == "text/xml" and request.body:
            try:
                filename = "my-request.xml"
                file_path = "request-files/"
                if not os.path.exists(path):
                    os.makedirs(path)
                with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'wb') as f:
                    f.write(data_to_process)
                return HttpResponse(status=200)

            except Exception as e:
                print("Something went wrong => {}".format(e))
                return HttpResponse(status=500)
        
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status=404)
```

Instead of receiving an XML file as I used to from other providers, I receive binary code that I can not open:

```
��]�n�8�}�WyTLRԅ��T��Q@.�$�:g^����%C��J�̼�g�[��ٺ9�-鷺ɞmL�S1o"�6�E�\;\f�����Aϲ�|�����2���(o���x�������,��u�ix<
�R�g��(��yv����E�Y]⺰8*�7q�WM�C1�ǎ��~[&딏��'�N�4�����M��M�.�(����|��h���2��w��Z&o��ϳqTT���mC㻻���^�e�$�o9��Ƣ~���!;��:[Iz�mC����4J�5`�Z,f��?�:-�IR?|��UZ�O�X����0�"�Y�X�߼��77އÞ�p����s��,��/��Y]�Q<-��㛤XUa����r�;�54e�~���H0��0���B���[����8�N��{���rs
�+{�6f���4�*Wr�$|�x���?�$m�d�mڦ:m�MNu��$����N����,)�Fiv��E����ɛ�a������r������p��u���8��Λ�E�:�f��x���.�4��sx�q���������z�m������
yv�%%�W���x��F��X�E�����}\����@�I����ӯMx�����í��m�N��J�g�2/^j�N�6��4��o=y۔�u�����h��C����:�2�I�A/�y���C�^6�v��+��C�,�����M��1�W������|�%�[̾���~\��RWY�͒tz<J��t<��tPd�d/�����4O�9���(��E
��
```

The XML file that I should be receiving looks like this:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><d2LogicalModel xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" modelBaseVersion="2" xsi:schemaLocation="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0 http://sdbby.heuboe.de:11447/d2Schema/StrategicRouting.xsd"><exchange><supplierIdentification><country>de</country><nationalIdentifier>DE-BY-SDB</nationalIdentifier></supplierIdentification></exchange><payloadPublication xsi:type="SituationPublication" lang="de"><publicationTime>2020-07-22T16:21:00+02:00</publicationTime><publicationCreator><country>de</country><nationalIdentifier>DE-BY-SDB</nationalIdentifier></publicationCreator><situation id="S1595414940876" version="1"><situationVersionTime>2020-07-22T12:49:00+02:00</situationVersionTime><headerInformation><confidentiality>noRestriction</confidentiality><informationStatus>real</informationStatus></headerInformation><situationRecord xsi:type="GeneralNetworkManagement" id="R1595414940876" version="1"><situationRecordCreationTime>2020-07-22T12:49:00+02:00</situationRecordCreationTime><situationRecordVersionTime>2020-07-22T12:49:00+02:00</situationRecordVersionTime><probabilityOfOccurrence>certain</probabilityOfOccurrence><validity><validityStatus>definedByValidityTimeSpec</validityStatus><validityTimeSpecification><overallStartTime>2020-07-22T12:49:00+02:00</overallStartTime><overallEndTime>2020-07-22T16:23:00+02:00</overallEndTime></validityTimeSpecification></validity><cause xsi:type="NonManagedCause"><causeDescription><values><value lang="de">Optimierte Zielführung zu den Parkplätzen Messe</value><value lang="en">improved routing to parking area Munich Trade Fair</value></values></causeDescription><causeType>other</causeType></cause><groupOfLocations xsi:type="Area"><alertCArea><alertCLocationCountryCode>D</alertCLocationCountryCode><alertCLocationTableNumber>1</alertCLocationTableNumber><alertCLocationTableVersion>15.1</alertCLocationTableVersion><areaLocation><alertCLocationName><values><value lang="de">Großraum München</value></values></alertCLocationName><specificLocation>548</specificLocation></areaLocation></alertCArea></groupOfLocations><actionPlanIdentifier>S-14c</actionPlanIdentifier><operatorActionStatus>implemented</operatorActionStatus><complianceOption>advisory</complianceOption><generalNetworkManagementType>other</generalNetworkManagementType><generalNetworkManagementExtension><generalNetworkManagementExtended xsi:type="StrategicRouteManagement"><nameOfRouteManagement><values><value lang="de">A94 West - Riem 2 Parkhaus West</value>
                            </values>
                        </nameOfRouteManagement><triggerOrigin><location xsi:type="Point"><pointByCoordinates><pointCoordinates><latitude>48.137062</latitude><longitude>11.617391</longitude>
    </pointCoordinates>
</pointByCoordinates><pointExtension><openlrExtendedPoint><openlrPointLocationReference><openlrPointAlongLine><openlrSideOfRoad>right</openlrSideOfRoad><openlrOrientation>withLineDirection</openlrOrientation><openlrPositiveOffset>346</openlrPositiveOffset><openlrLocationReferencePoint><openlrCoordinate><latitude>48.13819</latitude><longitude>11.6146</longitude>
                    </openlrCoordinate><openlrLineAttributes><openlrFunctionalRoadClass>FRC2</openlrFunctionalRoadClass><openlrFormOfWay>singleCarriageway</openlrFormOfWay><openlrBearing>182</openlrBearing>
                    </openlrLineAttributes><openlrPathAttributes><openlrLowestFRCToNextLRPoint>FRC2</openlrLowestFRCToNextLRPoint><openlrDistanceToNextLRPoint>738</openlrDistanceToNextLRPoint>
                    </openlrPathAttributes>
                </openlrLocationReferencePoint><openlrLastLocationReferencePoint><openlrCoordinate><latitude>48.13779</latitude><longitude>11.62253</longitude>
                    </openlrCoordinate><openlrLineAttributes><openlrFunctionalRoadClass>FRC2</openlrFunctionalRoadClass><openlrFormOfWay>multipleCarriageway</openlrFormOfWay><openlrBearing>241</openlrBearing>
                    </openlrLineAttributes>
                </openlrLastLocationReferencePoint>
            </openlrPointAlongLine>
        </openlrPointLocationReference>
    </openlrExtendedPoint>
</pointExtension>
                            </location>
                        </triggerOrigin><route>
```

---

Instead of receiving an XML request, I receive a binary one.

## Q:

**Is there a different way to parse this data?**

**Did the data provider send the wrong data?**

I hope that someone can guide me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the response headers at the target website you will see:

```
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Which means the content is encoded using gzip (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding).

On a normal web browser you wouldn't ever see this because the browser is doing the decoding automatically.

**Python has a module called zlib with specific commands for decoding gzip encoding** (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html).

Once you've decoded the data you should be able to process it like normal XML.

Comment: Yes the gzip library decoded the contents! Using: `gzip.decompress(data)` was exactly what I needed. thank you!